# Bash script command and getting rid of shellcheck error SC2181

Tags: bash, shellcheck

I have the following bash script:

```
dpkg-query --show --showformat='${Status}\n' "$i" 2> \
      /dev/null | grep "install ok installed" &> /dev/null
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
  l_var_is_desktop="true"
fi
```

and the ShellCheck utility (https://www.shellcheck.net/) is giving me the following output:

```
$ shellcheck myscript

Line 17:
    if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
          ^-- SC2181: Check exit code directly with e.g. 'if mycmd;', not indirectly with $?.

$
```

The link to this warning is the following: https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2181

What is the best way for modifying this.  The command is really too long to put into one line.  I would like to avoid using ShellCheck ignore rules.

I've tried creating a local variable and storing the output of the command, but this breaks other rules.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command doesn't really get much longer by putting it directly in `if`, you're just adding 3 characters.

```
if dpkg-query --show --showformat='${Status}\n' "$i" 2> \
    /dev/null | grep "install ok installed" &> /dev/null
then
    l_var_is_desktop="true"
fi
```

Comment: I wanted to keep the conditional small in term of length of characters, but for right now I am going to just use what you suggested.  Thank you.

Comment: You have to make a choice between appeasing `shellcheck.net` and your personal code style esthetics.